# Is there a way to change/update the thinkific liquid.view variables from the empire theme(or any other theme)?

Tags: templates, variables, view, liquid, liquid-layout

i have currently been working on the empire theme in thinkific plus platform. on Sign in page, there is a text "Welcome back !" above the signin form. i would like to change it as "Welcome back to my School of AAA".
currently i have commented the following in the signin_form

- where would i edit this "header_welcome_back" text/value?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I know this is late but you can change it in theme library then edited code -> Sections->signin_form, change this **{{ 'liquid.views.sign_in_page.header_welcome_back' | translate }}** in

```
<article class="sign-in__form">
  <h2 class="page__heading">
   {{ 'liquid.views.sign_in_page.header_welcome_back' | translate }}
  </h2>
```

to {{ 'Welcome back to my School of AAA' }}