# How do you target the English version of Thinkific liquid.view variables?

Tags: variables, themes, liquid, multilingual

The Thinkific Empire theme states "Your Student Dashboard," in the header of the student dashboard. However, our users aren't referred to as "students". Thinkific has confirmed that there isn't direct access to change the text, and advised that the theme code could be updated. However, this text is within a translation variable, which Thinkific will not give guidance about. I'm trying to determine how to adjust the text without breaking the built in translation logic.  Here is the code within the theme:

```
<p class="student-dashboard__welcome">{{ 'liquid.views.student_dashboard.header_dashboard' | translate }}, {{ site.current_user.first_name_last_initial }}</p>
```

I would like to set the English value for the "liquid.views.student_dashboard.header_dashboard" variable. I of course could overwrite the code as is described in [question 61267685](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/61267685/is-there-a-way-to-change-update-the-thinkific-liquid-view-variables-from-the-emp), but that would break future translations work we're planning. My guess is that I could create an 'if' statement to target the specific English version of the variable, but I can't find documentation on how to target a specific language within Thinkific. Does someone have sample code for how to do this?

I have tried communicating with Thinkific support, and have tried looking up methods for targeting a specific language for liquid code and ruby code. I've also looked for documentation on how to target a specific language in Thinkific. So far I have not found documenation on how to do this. I'm hoping someone has sample code for applying code within a Thinkific theme for a target language.